# Enviar Parámetros conformados por COMBOBOX Y Varios TEXTBOX utilizando Método GET a través de un Formulario

Tags: php, javascript, html, formularios, get

necesito una pequeña ayuda con el siguiente código:

Tengo un formulario sencillo compuesto por 1 combobox(Select) y varios textbox(imputs)

Lo que necesito es que el usuario llene o no todos los campos , envíe los valores por dos botones , claro está que, cada botón es una página.php diferente que recibirá los mismos parámetros. Pero cada uno está programada para hacer algo distinto.

Como método de envío de parámetros por formulario que utilizo es GET

**Anexo mi código HTML**

```
<body>
    <form action="" id="form" method="GET" >
        <select id="controlselect" name="ordenar">
            <option value='0'>Seleccione</option>
            <option value='1'>General</option>
            <option value='2'>Producto</option>
        </select>
        <input type='text' name='txtFecha' size='6' maxlength='20' id='txtfecha'>
        <input type='text' name='txtFechaFinal' size='6' maxlength='20' id='txtfechafinal'>
        <input type='text' name='txtIdentificacion' size='6' maxlength='20' id='identificacion'>

        <a href="" id="Buscar"><button type="button">Buscar</button></a>
        <a href="" id="Generar"><button type="button">Generar</button></a>
    </form>
</body>
```

He logrado hacer que envíe solamente el combobox , pero al momento de tratar de adaptar mi código con los textbox , me he encontrado con errores.

Voy a mostrarles mi adaptación con un solo Textbox , que me están generando los errores

**Anexo mi Código JavaScript**

```
<script>

    let btnBuscar = document.getElementById('Buscar');
    let btnGenerar = document.getElementById('Generar');

    $("#controlselect").change(function()
    {
        valor = $("#controlselect").value();
    });


    $("#Buscar").click(function(){
        valor1 = $("#txtfecha").val();

    });

    btnBuscar.setAttribute('href',`Prueba8.php?valor=${valor}`+`${valor1}`);
    btnGenerar.setAttribute('href',`Prueba9.php?valor=${valor}`+`${valor1}`);
</script>
```

**Anexo mi Código PHP para pruebas**

```
<?php

$v1 = $_GET['valor'];
$v2 = $_GET['valor1'];
echo("Variable: $v1");
echo("Variable: $v2");

?>
```

Me gustaría que me dijeran el problema y si pueden darme una solución adaptada a mi código o si es necesario , una nueva.

Agradecido de antemano!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varios errores:

- `valor = $("#controlselect").value();` si vas a usar `jQuery` así no se obtiene el valor, es con `.val()`.
- `Prueba8.php?valor=${valor}`+`${valor1}`, esta no es la forma de concatenar, cuando usas [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) ya no hace falta usar el `+` para concatenar, además para pasar datos por URL si te haz dado cuenta cuando entras a una página que usa filtros aparece esto `www.lapagina.com/busqueda.php?id=dfg543&longitud=23434...` ese `Ampersand` funciona para agregar otro valor a la URL, entonces lo hacemos de la siguiente forma `Prueba9.php?selectVal=${selectVal}&date=${date}&fFinal=${fFinal}&id=${id}`.

Esta vez quitamos el `change` del select ya que vas a enviar los valores cuando apriete cualquier botón y lo vamos a enviar con un `window.location.href`, espero te funcione, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  let btnBuscar = document.getElementById('Buscar');
    let btnGenerar = document.getElementById('Generar');

$('#Buscar').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

let selectVal = $("#controlselect").val();
let date = $('#txtfecha').val();
let fFinal = $('#txtfechafinal').val();
let id = $('#identificacion').val();

//para que observes como se genera la URL con los datos que ingresas
console.log(`Prueba9.php?selectVal=${selectVal}&date=${date}&fFinal=${fFinal}&id=${id}`);

//descomentalo cuando lo uses en tu código
//window.location.href= `Prueba9.php?selectVal=${selectVal}&date=${date}&fFinal=${fFinal}&id=${id}`;

});

$('#Generar').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

let selectVal = $("#controlselect").val();
let date = $('#txtfecha').val();
let fFinal = $('#txtfechafinal').val();
let id = $('#identificacion').val();

//para que observes como se genera la URL con los datos que ingresas
console.log(`Prueba8.php?selectVal=${selectVal}&date=${date}&fFinal=${fFinal}&id=${id}`);

//descomentalo cuando lo uses en tu código
//window.location.href= `Prueba8.php?selectVal=${selectVal}&date=${date}&fFinal=${fFinal}&id=${id}`;


});



})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <form action="" id="form" method="GET" >
        <select id="controlselect" name="ordenar">
            <option value='0'>Seleccione</option>
            <option value='1'>General</option>
            <option value='2'>Producto</option>
        </select>
        <input type='text' name='txtFecha' size='6' maxlength='20' id='txtfecha'>
        <input type='text' name='txtFechaFinal' size='6' maxlength='20' id='txtfechafinal'>
        <input type='text' name='txtIdentificacion' size='6' maxlength='20' id='identificacion'>

        <button type="button" id="Buscar">Buscar</button>
        <button type="button" id="Generar">Generar</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

**EN PHP**

```
   <?php

    $v1 = $_GET['selectVal'];
    $v2 = $_GET['date'];
    $v3 = $_GET['fFinal'];
    $v4 = $_GET['id'];
    echo("Variable: $v1");
    echo("Variable: $v2");
    echo("Variable: $v3");
    echo("Variable: $v4");

    ?>
```

Comment: Perfecto, veo que estoy mejorando ^^!.

Nuevamente agradecido por tu colaboración!

Comment: No hay de que un gusto poder ayudar! :D